# Returning a multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
void createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, int array[3][3]){

    int state[3][3];

    for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++){

            if(x == a && y == b){
                state[x][y] = array[c][d];
            }
            else if(x == c && y == d){
                state[x][y] = array[a][b];
            }
            else{
                state[x][y] = array[x][y];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            cout << state[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

I have basically got this function which clones the multidimensional array that is inputed but swaps the values of the two co-ordinates (a,b) and (c,d) around. This is then outputted out to the console.

However what I would really like is for this to be returned as a multidimensional array, but I don't think this can be done?

I have looked at vectors and pointers but don't really understand them and if I use them, I will then have to change all the previous code I have written.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think there is a need for MCVE here. The question is simple: returning a 2D array from a function.

Comment: @bolov Where's the _`return`_ actually? What's the actual inputs/outputs/errors?

Comment: @bolov Thats correct! Is it possible?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `array` is the input 2D array. `state` is the 2D array he wants to return.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there isn't any return type at the moment I am just the result out, however that is what I am wanting

Comment: @bolov If you know a concise answer to fix this, move on please.

Comment: @James technically no, it is not possible to return an array. You can however go around this shortcoming by passing an array to the function or by returning a pointer to a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @James You want to have a `int [3][3];` type returned?

Comment: You should just use a vector of vectors.  The beauty of vectors is that you shouldn't have to rewrite all of the previous code you've written; much of it will still work because the syntax to dereference elements is the same.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to return a non conventional data type (`int`, `char` etc), the best way of doing it is by making your very own one.

```
struct mat3
{
    int myArray[3][3];    
};


mat3 createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, int array[3][3]){

mat3 state;

for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<3;y++){

        if(x == a && y == b){
            state.myArray[x][y] = array[c][d];
        }
        else if(x == c && y == d){
            state.myArray[x][y] = array[a][b];
        }
        else{
            state.myArray[x][y] = array[x][y];
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        cout << state.myArray[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return state;
}

}
```

> I have looked at vectors and pointers but don't really understand them and if I use them, I will then have to change all the previous code I have written

I suggest you study pointers further, they are so essential that you are already using them without knowing it.

Comment: "by making your very own" - looks like a typo. What does this mean?

Comment: Make your own data type. In this case you are making a type called 'mat3'.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple options.

Option 1 - pass the array to the function

```
void createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, const int array[3][3], int outArray[3][3]){
...
}
```

Option 2 - return a reference to an array - just **make sure the array does not live on the stack** of the function it's returned from.

```
typedef int My3Times3Array[3][3];
const My3Times3Array& createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, const int array[3][3]){
...
}
```

Option 3 - return a class that contains an array

```
struct Array
{
    int array[3][3];    
};

...

Array createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, const int array[3][3]){
...
}
```

There's also [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/), or [`boost::matrix`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm), but since you mentioned you aren't comfortable with pointers yet, I'd save template classes for later.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically allocate a two-dimensional array and return pointer to it. For example

```
typedef int ( *STATE )[3];

STATE createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, int array[3][3]){

    STATE state = new int[3][3];

    //...

    return state;
}
```

Or

```
int ( *createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, int array[3][3] ) )[3]{

    int ( * state )[3] = new int[3][3];

    //...

    return state;
}
```

In fact the same result you can get if you will use vectors. For example

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

//...
std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> createArray(int a, int b, int c, int d, int array[3][3]){

    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> state( 3 );

    //...

    return state;
}
```

Comment: In c++, using pointers is usually not advised. Also, `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>` is sufficiently different from `int[3][3]` to make some additional explanation necessary.

Comment: Which is stupid and non-sense waste of program time, as the array size is already known.

Comment: @Jako  I showed the general approach how arrays are allocated and how to work with pointers. It is not a stupid approach as you think. It is a flexible approach that will work with arrays of any size.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Would it be better to use `typedef int STATE[3]` and have the function return `STATE*`? I guess it's functionally equivalent (not sure) but more readable.